# Is update_or_create safe within atomic transaction?

Tags: django

The title is pretty explicit : can you use an update_or_create command inside an atomic transaction in django ?

I don't find the answer in [the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create). There is something about race condition, but atomic transaction is about rollback more than race ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The django atomic transaction end up managing a "BEGIN TRANSACTION;" sql statement at it's begining and either a "COMMIT;" or a "ROLLBACK;" statement at it's ending.

Any SQL statement in between the begining and ending can be commited or rollbacked in a whole. This include statements use to update_or_create objects. This whole process is handled out of the box by the database engine.

The real question is why would update_or_create be not safe in an atomic transaction.

The race condition comment belong to an other principle where it could be possible to create 2 time the same record but with different ids if certain conditions are not met. Defining field uniqueness is one of the tools in order to avoid such kind of problem.

Comment: This is not as trivial as it sound... I ran into serious trouble some time ago working on a database managed through pandas "to_sql" shortcut method (which doesn't or didn't managed transaction very well). Since then (call that a phobia), I tried to stay away from shortcut methods. Given that I'm neither very fond nor expert about Django'ORM, a 3rd party advice was really needed before doing some mess ! Thanks !